# Run CentOS 7 live from USB

Tags: centos, usb, live-usb, iso

I downloaded CentOS 7 from http://mirror.yourwebhoster.eu/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1503-01.iso and put it on to an USB.

But when starting the computer with the USB in it, I only get the option to install CentOS 7.[image: CentOS 7 from USB]

But I want to start CentOS 7 live from USB without any installation. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to use the live CD image instead of the installer image. On your mirror, the default live CD is available at http://mirror.yourwebhoster.eu/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveCD-1503.iso; in http://mirror.yourwebhoster.eu/centos/7/isos/x86_64/ you can find GNOME and KDE live CDs too.